# Is this query non compatible with php? It there a glaringly obvious syntax error because I can't get it to run

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, codeigniter-3

So, I am currently making a dashboard for my boss, displaying data from a logistics perspective, he has sent me his own MS Access query, for the life of my I cannot make it run, in an attempt to make a table our worker can view from the data it should be pulling. Is anything glaringly wrong with it?

I'm just an apprentice, but my seniors have suggested that everything with ORDER requires [] around it to run through PHP and codeigniter, I have tried altering the syntax through a validator, yet i seem to have hit a brick wall. Below is the original.

```
function order_table()
    {   
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $macsdb = $this->load->database('macs', TRUE);

$query = $macsdb->query("SELECT temp123.Hour, temp123.User, Count(temp123.[ORDER]) AS CountOfORDER, Sum(temp123.SumOfCountOfPRODUCT) AS SumOfSumOfCountOfPRODUCT, Sum(temp123.SumOfSumOfQUANTITY) AS SumOfSumOfSumOfQUANTITY
FROM (SELECT temp456.Hour, temp456.User, temp456.[ORDER], Sum(temp456.CountOfPRODUCT) AS SumOfCountOfPRODUCT, Sum(temp456.SumOfQUANTITY) AS SumOfSumOfQUANTITY
FROM (SELECT WHAUDIT.Date, Format([Time],'hh') AS [Hour], WHAUDIT.User, WHAUDIT.[ORDER], Count(WHAUDIT.PRODUCT) AS CountOfPRODUCT, Sum(WHAUDIT.QUANTITY) AS SumOfQUANTITY
FROM WHAUDIT
WHERE (((WHAUDIT.type)='I11' Or (WHAUDIT.type)=' 11'))
GROUP BY WHAUDIT.Date, Format([Time],'hh'), WHAUDIT.User, WHAUDIT.[ORDER]
HAVING (((WHAUDIT.Date)='$date')) as temp456
GROUP BY temp456.Hour, temp456.User, temp456.[ORDER]) as temp123
GROUP BY temp123.Hour, temp123.User
ORDER BY temp123.Hour DESC;");

     return $query->result();
        $macsdb->close();        
    }
```

The query by itself is as follows:

```
SELECT
  temp123.Hour,
  temp123.User,
  Count(temp123.[ORDER]) AS CountOfORDER,
  Sum(temp123.SumOfCountOfPRODUCT) AS SumOfSumOfCountOfPRODUCT,
  Sum(temp123.SumOfSumOfQUANTITY) AS SumOfSumOfSumOfQUANTITY
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      temp456.Hour,
      temp456.User,
      temp456.[ORDER],
      Sum(temp456.CountOfPRODUCT) AS SumOfCountOfPRODUCT,
      Sum(temp456.SumOfQUANTITY) AS SumOfSumOfQUANTITY
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          WHAUDIT.Date,
          Format([Time], 'hh') AS [Hour],
          WHAUDIT.User,
          WHAUDIT.[ORDER],
          Count(WHAUDIT.PRODUCT) AS CountOfPRODUCT,
          Sum(WHAUDIT.QUANTITY) AS SumOfQUANTITY
        FROM
          WHAUDIT
        WHERE
          (
            (
              (WHAUDIT.type) = 'I11'
              Or (WHAUDIT.type) = ' 11'
            )
          )
        GROUP BY
          WHAUDIT.Date,
          Format([Time], 'hh'),
          WHAUDIT.User,
          WHAUDIT.[ORDER]
        HAVING
          (((WHAUDIT.Date) = '$date')) as temp456
        GROUP BY
          temp456.Hour,
          temp456.User,
          temp456.[ORDER]
      ) as temp123
    GROUP BY
      temp123.Hour,
      temp123.User
    ORDER BY
      temp123.Hour DESC;
```

I have been trying to produce the results using the echo function to populate a table, I haven't gotten as far as I have yet to make it work. It seems to be a query, within a query, within a query. Any advice would be much appreciated.

I have tried square bracketing all instances of ORDER as it is apparently an essential part of it that won't be read properly without it. I have tried running it through a validator but this throws up various issues because of the brackets also. I also know that it seems to really not like the format Time section for some reason.

The goal of this query is to be able to populate a table from the results on a Codeigniter view page. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does MS Access allow multiple `GROUP BY ` clauses - looks unusual?

Comment: make the php echo the query instead of executing it. Then run it directly in the command line and see the errors raised. Also implement in this code the error reporting so that you can see the syntax errors for the query too.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: @NigelRen There's one `GROUP BY` clause per subquery, that's all fine.

Comment: SQL is usually quite happy to tell you where, or at the very least give clues about where things went wrong. Find the error message and start from there.

Comment: Check that HAVING clause, 3 open brackets and 3 close brackets... ie, you're not closing the subquery

Comment: You should at least tell us what is the error you get.

Comment: For one, `Date` and `Order` are also keywords that need to be bracketed (Aside from that `HAVING` clause being an issue). Check the [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/sql-reserved-words).

Comment: Thankyou all, I'll give these a go, It's just quite a difficult task as when I'm editing the view it's obviously erroring and that stops the workers viewing the stats screen. I'll check back soon and make a note of key errors I come across :)

Comment: Just start by firing up Access and making sure it works there. It's way easier to debug an Access query on Access than doing it while executing it through php

Answer (score 0):

Date value expressions in Access are wrapped in octothorpes, so either:

```
HAVING (((WHAUDIT.Date)=#$date#)) as temp456
```

or, if it today's date:

```
HAVING (((WHAUDIT.Date)=Date())) as temp456
```

Also, the leading space here looks weird:

```
Or (WHAUDIT.type) = ' 11'
```